# Problem referencing from another workbook using VBA because I want to do countif

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I just begin to learn VBA and this is my assignment question. It requires me to use a range of data from my workbook named 17067513_Excel. I have to use COUNTIF to find out how many cells contain more than 40 marks. Can you look at my code and help me

```
Sub Test()
    Dim iVal As Integer
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("17067513_Excel.xlsx").Worksheets("17067513").Range("N2:N296"), ">40%")
Sheets("VBA").[B1] = iVal
End Sub
```

Comment: the code you show above included in the same workbook from which you want to calculate the countif or included in another workbook?

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with your code. Therefore check spelling. Is the referenced workbook of xlsx format? Is there an underscore in its name? Is it open? (If it is closed the path must be supplied.) Is there a worksheet by the given name in the workbook? Is there a space in the worksheet's name (beginning or end)? Insert `Debug.Print "iVal = "; iVal` following the CountIf to check if a value is returned. Finally, it's not clear why 40% should equal "40 marks" and you don't state what kind of error your code is producing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a code to calculate COUNTIF and both data ( the range you need for the calculation) & code included in the same workbook you can try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Countif()

    Dim Result As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1706751").Range("N2:N296")

    Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(rng, ">40%")

End Sub
```

**Note:** Save you workbook as Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)

Comment: hi guys its from another workbook. Im very sorry i didnt point out earlier.

Comment: i found out if its from the same workbook i could have completed it earlier.

Comment: There is an underscore in the name of the another workbook named "17067513_Excel".The workbook is open. The worksheet name is "17067513" and no space in beginning and end. The reason i insert "40%" is because the value in "N2:N296" consists of marks from 0 to 100 in the workbook.

Comment: Im very grateful and thankful for ur help and may god bless u all in ur future endeavours